# How to avoid CTQ operator in DB2 Blu with substr?

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

I'm working with DB2 Blu, and I often have problems in my queries plan with SUBSTR as the CTQ operator is not high enough.

Here is an example :

```
select
coalesce(annee,annee_semaine),
count(JOUR_OUVRE)
from d_tps_calendrier
group by grouping sets((annee),(annee_semaine))
```

The query plan is all right :

```
Rows 
            RETURN
            (   1)
             Cost 
              I/O 
              |
             2701 
            L   TQ
            (   2)
            334.257 
              224 
              |
             2701 
              C TQ
            (   3)
            333.573 
              224 
              |
             2701 
            UNION 
            (   4)
            332.721 
              224 
            /-+--\
         2649      52 
        GRPBY    GRPBY 
        (   5)   (  10)
        166.197  166.107 
          112      112 
          |        |
         22310    22310 
        TBSCAN   TBSCAN
        (   6)   (  11)
        165.176  165.176 
          112      112 
          |        |
         22310    22310 
        TEMP     TEMP  
        (   7)   (   7)
        147.121  147.121 
          112      112 
          |
         22310 
        GRPBY 
        (   8)
        134.404 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        TBSCAN
        (   9)
        132.702 
          112 
          |
         22310 
  CO-TABLE: INFIFZ00
 D_TPS_CALENDRIER_INF
          Q1
```

Now, what I really want to do is a group by the first 3 characters of annee_semaine :

```
select
coalesce(annee,substr(annee_semaine,1,3)),
count(JOUR_OUVRE)
from d_tps_calendrier
group by grouping sets((annee),(substr(annee_semaine,1,3)))
```

And now in the query plan, the group by and union are done after the CTQ operator

```
Rows 
            RETURN
            (   1)
             Cost 
              I/O 
              |
             2701 
            UNION 
            (   2)
            431.235 
              224 
            /-+--\
         2649      52 
        GRPBY    GRPBY 
        (   3)   (  14)
        220.453  210.366 
          112      112 
          |        |
         2649     22310 
        TBSCAN   TBSCAN
        (   4)   (  15)
        220.219  208.372 
          112      112 
          |        |
         2649     22310 
        SORT     TEMP  
        (   5)   (   7)
        220.219  190.317 
          112      112 
          |
         22310 
        TBSCAN
        (   6)
        208.372 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        TEMP  
        (   7)
        190.317 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        LM  TQ
        (   8)
        181.039 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        GRPBY 
        (   9)
        165.712 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        TBSCAN
        (  10)
        163.749 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        SORT  
        (  11)
        161.817 
          112 
          |
         22310 
          C TQ
        (  12)
        132.866 
          112 
          |
         22310 
        TBSCAN
        (  13)
        132.702 
          112 
          |
         22310 
  CO-TABLE: INFIFZ00
 D_TPS_CALENDRIER_INF
          Q1
```

I tried with left instead of substr, without success. Is there a good pratice to deal with substr in DB2 Blu ?

In others cases, I was able to directly put de substr in one column in the table, mais in this case it is not possible.

Comment: To be complete, the second query plan is by using SUBSTRING and not SUBSTR. In this simplified example, with SUBSTR the query plan is all right, but in the real more complex query, even with SUBSTR it is not.

Comment: What version of Db2? There are improvements in every modpack and new version

Comment: Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.4.4", "s1902261400", "DYN1902261400AIX",
and Fix Pack "4a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick :

```
select
coalesce(annee,cast(annee_semaine as vargraphic(3))),
count(JOUR_OUVRE)
from d_tps_calendrier
group by grouping sets((annee),(cast(annee_semaine as vargraphic(3))))
```

It is not perfect as it only works as long as I want to have the firsts characters and not something like substr(str,4,5)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a column to the table that is generated always, something like:

```
annee_semaine3 char(3) generated always as (substring(annee_semaine,1,3)) implicitly hidden
```

You can then group by this hidden column.

```
select
coalesce(annee,substr(annee_semaine,1,3)),
count(JOUR_OUVRE)
from d_tps_calendrier
group by grouping sets((annee),(annee_semaine3))
```

You can also explicitly reference it in the select clause to avoid that calculation.

Because the column is hidden, operations like `select *` will no include it; it must be explicitly named.

Comment: Generated columns cannot be added to existing column-organized tables even in 11.5. One must recreate and reload a table with such a generated column.

Comment: I will keep this method in mind, but for now I will avoid reloading the table as it's use in multiple schemas